# Javascript - check if user is editing text input

Tags: javascript, function, input, coffeescript, keypress

Can you check if the user is editing a text field without editing anything? I want a function to be called when the user is in a text field and presses enter. I know it would work with a form.

Coffee:

```
$(document).keyup (e) -> 
  func()  if e.which is 13 and "user is in input field"
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13 and "user is in input field") {
        func();
    }
});
```

Comment: "user is in input field" ? What is that in JavaScript ?

Comment: That's the question, lol.

Comment: And to what purpose do you not want to put a form around it?

Comment: It was easier to make a submit button with an image than with a button that has to be styled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `.on()` method to create a delegated event handler that is bound to the `document` but only calls your handler function if the target element matches a selector of your choice:

```
$(document).on('keypress', 'input[type="text"],textarea', function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
        // do something here
    }
});
```

(This is similar to Musa's answer, except jQuery does the `.is()` test for you automatically.)

Note the selector in the second argument is `'input[type="text"],textarea'` so as to exclude non-text inputs.

Answer (score 3):

I would check if the input field in *on focus* using jQuery:

```
var selectedInput = null;
$(function() {
    $('input, textarea, select').focus(function() {
        selectedInput = this;
    }).blur(function(){
        selectedInput = null;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the focus state as Yair Nevet did because you might need the test in other event callbacks like onbeforeunload.

```
"user is in a field or something" = $( "input:focus,textarea:focus" ).length > 0
```

The jQuery doc states 
"If you are looking for the currently focused element, $( document.activeElement ) will retrieve it without having to search the whole DOM tree."

So maybe

```
$( document.activeElement ).filter('input,textarea').length > 0
```

So :

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13 and $( document.activeElement ).filter('input,textarea').length > 0) {
        func();
    }
});
```

[jQuery doc](http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/)

Comment: Wouldn't either option return true if the the focus is on _any_ control (including buttons, select elements, etc.)?

Comment: I just dislike the key event approach

Comment: _"I just dislike the key event approach"_ - Maybe so, but it's a bit hard to test for when the user presses enter without using a key event...

Comment: I'm talking about the focus state detection. The test might be useful on other event callbacks like onbeforeunload.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('input').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        // do whatever you want
    }
});
```

Comment: That's not the question I think

Comment: @ArmelLarcier : Oh really? How so ?

Comment: "user is in a field" can't be summarized to "user has released a key in a field"... The focus is in question here or am I mistaking?

Comment: @ArmelLarcier - "I want a function to be called when the user is in a text field _and presses enter._"

Comment: Yes, it should only be called when user is editing the textfield. (when he has clicked on it)

Comment: @xprise - "when he has clicked on it" is a different (and overly specific) requirement - I'm pretty sure you don't mean that, because the user may have gotten to the field via the keyboard (tabbing)...

Comment: I knew there was something odd here. FOCUS!  ;-)
I say Yair Nevet has it.

Comment: @ArmelLarcier : What's the necessity of writing a focus for this!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the target element to check which field is in focus

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13 && $(e.target).is('input,textarea')) {
        func();
    }
});
```

`$(e.target).is('input,textarea')` returns true if the element the keypress event originated was a text box.

Coffee:

```
$(document).keypress (e) ->
   func()  if e.which is 13 and $(e.target).is("input,textarea")
```